# Highlight cells that don't have number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I was looking to create a true/false formula that is able to view a cell and determine whether it has a number in it (data type is 'Text').

E.g. Cells

[image]

Where as the desired output is:

[image]

Note: special characters like "_" or "-" are ignored.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try using this formula, `=MAX(IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(ROW($48:$57)),A1),""))>0`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - I'm a little bit confused as to what I should change ROW($48:$57) to, to fit my sheet? What values should go inside the ROW section?

Comment: All good, this seems to work =COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1))

Comment: Basically ROW($48:$57) returns the numbers 48 to 57, when wrapping the same within CHAR it shall returns the character specified, so it finds whether there are numbers between 0-9, if it finds then its wrapped within a `MAX()` Function and if it doesnt it gives 0, so which is false

Comment: All good there is no harm, whatever suits you best, you can use it, ! This came into my mind so i shared.

Comment: While you have hard coded, within a `FIND()` Function, which i havent. BTW you can use it in this way as well, `=COUNT(FIND(CHAR(ROW($48:$57)),A1))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Actually seems like with my formula, it doesn't allow me to create a condition as it gives the error "You may not use reference operations (such as unions, inter...), array constants or the LAMDA function for conditional formatting criteria". Your formula seems to work fine when I put it in a cell, however when I put it in a conditional formula to highlight - its highlighting some of the wrong content.

Comment: Yes thats the reason why i have used, since you mentioned that you want to use in CF, curly brackets or unions doesnt work not only in CF

Comment: All good seems to be working now, HUGE THANKS! @MayukhBhattacharya

Comment: Shall i share it in answers so that in future someone looking for a solution shall help

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya yep I reckon that would be a good idea

Comment: since it has worked you can accept the same as an answer/upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have ***tried***, and come up with,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **B1**

```
=MAX(IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(ROW($48:$57)),A1),""))>0
```

Basically this part `FIND(CHAR(ROW($48:$57)),A1)` check whether there is a number or not, if it finds it, then we can use either `MAX()` or `MIN()` or `COUNT()` function to get the respective values. And then using a **`Boolean`** to check whether `TRUE` or `FALSE`

---

Or, You may use the `COUNT()` Function as well,

• Formula used in cell **E1**

```
=COUNT(FIND(CHAR(ROW($48:$57)),A1))>0
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

Use any one of the above formulas in Conditional Formatting Rules --> Use a formula to determine which cells to format. Shall highlight the one has a number along with it.